# Export sku & quantity using SQL

Tags: magento-1.9

Super-quick one. I'm hoping to get some assistance exporting `sku` and `qty` from an M1 database using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check if your Magento install uses a database prefix in app/etc/config.xml;

- if your database uses a database prefix, then each table in the query below need their name prepended with the prefix.
- with this in mind, the query below will give you sku,qty for all your
  simple products in your Magento 1 catalog.

> select sku,qty from cataloginventory_stock_item stock  inner join
>   catalog_product_entity e on e.entity_id=stock.product_id and
>   e.type_id='simple';

then the simplest is to use phpmyadmin and export the result.